# Inheriting background color in nested tables?

Tags: html, css

```
th 
{
    background-color: #cc6600;
}
.nested_table th
{
    background-color: none;
}
```

Despite setting the background-color property for the headings in the nested table to none, I still get the orange color (#cc6600) that I set in a rule for `<th>` earlier.

The rule for the nested table's `<th>` is below the rule for `<th>` in the CSS and hence would be given higher preference. Also, it is more specific.

Why then is the orange color not overridden?

Another observation that I made was that although setting background color to none may seem erroneous, it is not. If I were to change the background color property of the `<th>` rule, the rules below (`.alternate` and `.nested_table th`) still evaluate. This could not have been possible if setting background color to none was erroneous as the browser would have stopped reading the file from that point on wards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Background-color` can't be set to `none`, the default value is `transparent`.

```
.nested_table th {background-color: transparent;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnaw5ay3/

The second way, using `none` is

```
.nested_table th {background: none}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnaw5ay3/1/

Comment: I think you are right. But if it can't be set to none, the rules following the rule with the wrong declaration should no longer be evaluated. But they do evaluate, why is that?

Comment: @user3760100: invalid  values are just ignored and have no effect to other properties in the rule. When you set invalid value, the last valid, or the default value is used for this property. And last valid is `#c60` for all `TH`s in this table.

Answer (score 2):

Use transparent instead of none:

```
.nested_table th
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```